# Handle Express-JWT Error In Composable Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

I'm implementing JWT authorization for each API like below:

**auth.js**

```
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt';
import compose from 'composable-middleware';

var validateJwt = expressJwt({
  secret: config.secrets.session
});

function isAuthenticated() {
    return compose()

    .use(function(req, res, next) {
       validateJwt(req, res, next);
    })
    .use(function(req, res, next) {

    User.find({
            where: {
         id: req.user.id
            }
    }).then(function(user){

            //Handle User
        }).catch(function(err){
            //Handle DB Error
        });
    });
}
```

**index.js**

```
import auth from '../../auth';
import express from 'express';
import controller from './user_group.controller';
import * as validators from './user_group.validations';

// Create router object
const router = express.Router();

// Get all user groups
router.get('/', [auth.isAuthenticated(), validators.index], controller.index);
```

Everything is working absolutely fine except error handling of JWT. I'm not understanding the function `validateJwt(req, res, next);` that how to handle the `Unauthorized Error stack` before moving to the next middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it using the following:

```
.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

  if(err) {
    return res.status(constants.INVALID_OR_NO_ACCESS_TOKEN.code).json({
      status: 'error',
      code: constants.INVALID_OR_NO_ACCESS_TOKEN.code,
      message: constants.INVALID_OR_NO_ACCESS_TOKEN.message
    }).end();
  }
  User.find({
    where: {
      id: req.user.id
    }
  })
```

Comment: This works, however, it cannot capture "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
" error...

Answer (score 1):

You can add another .use after validateJwt

```
return compose()
       .use(function(req,res,next){
             validateJwt(req, res, next);
            })
        .use(function(err, req,res,next){
                if(err){
                 //here you will catch the error generated by the validateJWT
                 // eg: return res.status(401).json(err.message);
                 // or: return next(err);
                 }
                 else{
                    next();
                 }

             })
```